# MacBook Pro does not power on sometimes

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have a MacBook Pro 15″ Late 2008 (5,1). Sometimes it just won't power on. It works fine. I shutdown, then when I go to turn no it just does nothing. Previously I removed the battery and the charger, pressed the power button for a few seconds (so as capacitors can decharge etc) and then it powered on. The last 2 times, I couldn't turn it on for two days. After two days I just pressed the power button and it turned on.

Note that no water has been spilled or anything like that. Are there any recommendations? Any known issues with workarround?

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as something making the power key stick - I used to have this problem with my 2008 Macbook Pro 15". If you dropped it in the past this can cause wiring to come lose (had this problem too!) despite everything else appearing to work normally.

Definitely get it fully backed up ASAP and then have it checked out.

Answer (score 0):

MACBOOKS HAVE A SAFETY MECHANISM FOR HUMIDITY. Observe, if your macbook does not turn on on rainy days, especially when you live in tropics where humidity and condensation are extreme, do the following : unscrew the screws, remove the back lid and dry the inside with hairdryer for about a minute. Also you can take your mackbook for a short while to an air conditioned room, which also makes it turn on. Google this topic, there are more reports of this and also solutions available. Crazy, huh ? Of course you should not keep electronics in such humid conditions but realistically, how are you supposed to comply with that in some climates ? I was agonizing with this for a year before I came up the idea to google something so insane... and that indeed was the cause and solutions.